# Apache FTP Server stop session programmatically

Tags: java, apache, ftp

I am developing a chatting system using TCP socket to exchange message and Apache FTP Server to exchange file. When a client socket disconnect with server socket (no longer exchange message), I also want to terminate all FTP sessions opened by client. After searching Internet with no answer (the official document doesn't help, either), I took a quick exploration into Apache FTP Server source code and came up with a dirty solution:

```
public void disconnectFTPSessionFromClient(String clientIP) {
    Set<FtpIoSession> sessions = ftpServer.getListener("default").getActiveSession();
    for (FtpIoSession s : sessions) {
        if (clientIP.equals(s.getFtpletSession().getClientAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress())) {
            s.close(false).awaitUninterruptibly(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

So far, the code worked as intended, but I am still afraid someday it will break the server. Can anyone show me the proper way to end a FTP session of Apache FTP Server?

Comment: A well implementing FTP server will be able to clean up all resources left by unexpected client behavior.

Comment: @LutzHorn Yes, I aslo hope that, too. But without a clear understanding of the Apache FTP Server's internal mechanism, I cannot be sure my solution won't break the server. And I don't have enough time to read all Apache FTP Server source code. Their documentation is very poor and doesn't help much, by the way.